# Downloading RGB Sentinel-2 with Google Earth Engine and Python

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, rgb, google-earth-engine-python-api, jupyter-notebook

I am fairly new to the Google Earth Engine platform, and I want to create a dataset for my machine learning project using the aforesaid platform. As far I have this code for downloading a single picture:

```
import ee
 
# Trigger the authentication flow.
ee.Authenticate()
 
# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize()

geoJSON = ... # coordinates of rectangle
coords = geoJSON['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords)

ffa_db = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD') 
                       .filterBounds(aoi) 
                       .filterDate(ee.Date('2020-08-01'), ee.Date('2020-08-31')) 
                       .first() 
                       .clip(aoi))

url = ffa_db.select('VV').getThumbURL({'min': -20, 'max': 0})
```

After that, I just download a file with this command: `!wget {url}` (From Jupyter Notebook)
The question is fairly simple, but I had much struggled with it due to the lack of Pythonic ways of doing such things. I searched GEE Community tutorials and Github, but have no luck with them.

How can I download RGB images from Sentinel-2 using Python?

Better to download to a local directory rather than a Google disk.

Comment: what is wrong with the method you exposed? As far as I see you are downloading the image

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe this code sample is working, but how should I modify it to download images from COPERNICUS/S2 in RGB, because by changing ImageCollection to `ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')` and selected bands to `ffa_db.select('B4', 'B3', 'B2')` gives me blank image. I guess I don't understand how bands works, or I don't know what is the problem. I hope I have explained the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to define visualization parameters and then make a new variable where you add the visualization. It would look something like this:

```
var vis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  bands:['B4','B3','B2'],
};          

var ffa_db_new = ffa_db.visualize(vis);
```

And then you export the new variable `ffa_db_new` instead of the old one.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed an open-access Python library called pyeo at the University of Leicester. It allows automated search, download and processing of Sentinel-2 data and is available on Github. The library integrates with Sen2Cor so you can even do your own atmospheric correction. It further allows band stacking, reprojection, mosaicking and machine learning classification.

https://clcr.github.io/pyeo/